# Using only a 5-gallon bucket and a 3-gallon bucket put exactly four gallons of water in the 5-gallon bucket

Tags: logical-deduction, decanting-problems

Assuming you have an infinite supply of water.
No measurement markings on the buckets.
How do you fill the buckets in the right way?

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:

> Fill the 3 gallon bucket, and then pour the contents into the 5 gallon bucket

Step 2:

> Fill the 3 gallon bucket again, and pour its contents into the 5 gallon bucket until it is full.

Step 3:

> Empty the 5 gallon bucket, and move the remaining 1 gallon of water from the 3 gallon bucket to the 5 gallon bucket

Step 4:

> The same as Step 1, but this time you will end up with 4 gallons of water in the 5 gallon bucket rather than 3